# Is there a way I can import all the classes without importing specific classes in this case?

Tags: java, import, package

In this case, I had to import a enum inside one of the files I have already imported by using *. I'm forced to import it since it cannot resolve to a variable. Any suggestion to fix this? [Packages imported for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhLgQ.png)

Comment: You are talking about an `enum` declared inside a `class`, correct?

Comment: The real answer here is "use an IDE that manages all this for you".

Comment: @StephenC Yes, the enum is inside the class that I already imported by the package but I have to declare it separately to fix the issue.

Comment: You can either import the nested enum (e.g. `import some.pkg.Class1.MyEnum;`), or you can refer to it qualified by the type name of the enclosing class.  But yes, `import some.pkg.*` on-demand imports the top level classes of `some.pkg` ... and nothing else.  Note that this is consistent with `import some.pkg.*;` not importing "sub-packages".

Comment: There is no fix for this.  It is working ... as designed.

Comment: Please read over "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)", especially the sections on code and on image use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is this Android Studio if yes then :**

Use alt + enter to import classes in Android Studio
or use IDE Features just go to File>Setting>Editor>General>Auto Import

and configure as per your needs [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx4ra.png)

*If not go through your IDE settings*